# Angular select and ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to populate a select field with content from an array. I'm confused as to what exactly my "model" is.

I'm looking to access content from `ctrl.contents` which is an array of objects. I assume this is my "model".

ViewPage.html

```
<div>
  <select ng-model="ctrl.contents"
    ng-options="content.title.name in content.title.name as content in contents">

  </select>
</div>
```

`var ctrl = this` from ViewPage.controller.js

If I was to `console.log(ctrl.contents)` from ViewPage.controller.js the array of objects would be returned:

```
[
  > 0: ContentViewModel
    > title: Object  // Each numbered array object has similar contents 
      name: "Thomas"
      ...
  > 1: ContentViewModel
  > 2: ContentViewModel
  > 3: ContentViewModel
]
```

I can't seem to get the select field populated with anything. Am I getting the ng-model wrong?

Comment: Your object looks like this { title: object, name: "Thomas" } ? And in ng-options, you want to display 'name' ?

Comment: No the "name" flag falls under the "title" object. Sorry I should have indented that appropriately.

Comment: check this. https://jsfiddle.net/gargdeendayal/9Lnubb8u/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'model' is a separate variable that will contain the selected value of your select menu - set it to something like `ctrl.selectedItem`.

Your `ng-options` parameters should look like this:

```
ng-options="content.title.name for content in ctrl.contents"
```

For more info, refer to [this example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-select-with-ngoptions-and-setting-a-default-value) - checkout both the html and js in app.js.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks for explaining the model bit.

Answer (score 0):

This should be your html

```
<div>
  <select ng-model="ctrl.selectedContent"
ng-options="content.title.name for content in ctrl.contents" ng-value="content">

  </select>
</div>
```